# Why condition "else" doesn't work in my python code

Tags: python

here is my code.

```
highnum=100
lownum=0
guessnum=highnum/2
print "Please think of a number between 0 and 100!"
while True:
    print "Is your secret number is "+str(guessnum)+"?"
    print "Enter 'h' to indicate the guess is too high.",
    print "Enter 'l' to indicate the guess is too low. ",
    print "Enter 'c' to indicate I guessed correctly."
    result=raw_input()
    if result=="h":
        highnum=guessnum
        guessnum=int(highnum+lownum)/2
    if result=="l":
        lownum=guessnum
        guessnum=int(highnum+lownum)/2
    if result=="c":
        break
    else:
        print "Sorry, I did not understand your input."
print "Game over. Your secret number was: "+str(guessnum)+" ."
```

Everytime I type the input, it prints out "Sorry, I did not understand your input." The condition "else" doesn't work.

I don't know why. Could anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Because `else` is only attached to the last `if` statement. Use `elif` instead of `if` after `if`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because as written, each of your `if` statements are independent, the `else` only corresponds to your last `if result == 'c'`, so if they don't type `'c'`, they hit your `else` case.

Instead, you can use `if/elif/else` to try each of your cases.

```
if result=="h":
    highnum=guessnum
    guessnum=int(highnum+lownum)/2
elif result=="l":
    lownum=guessnum
    guessnum=int(highnum+lownum)/2
elif result=="c":
    break
else:
    print "Sorry, I did not understand your input."
```